# Trying to get the function to take 4 test scores and determine the students average score out of 320 points

Tags: python

```
def getExamPoints(examPoints):
    for examPoints in range(1, 5):
        examPoints = input("Please enter students exam scores: ")
    totalPoints = input("Please enter total possible points: ")
    print("The total exam points are: " + sum(int(examPoints)))
    avg = float(int(str(examPoints))/int(totalPoints))
    print("the average is: ", avg)
```

on Line 5 I am getting the error `'int object is not iterable'`
and I have no idea why.

I am attempting to write a program with functions and this portion of the function is suppose to take four homework scores each out of eighty points and calculate the average of the scores and then take that average and multiply it by the percentage that homework is worth for the class, but I cant even seem to get this chunk of the program to get an average of homework scores.  I am not very good with python, also if this isn't formatted correctly I apologize in advance, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: thanks for formatting that

Answer (score 2):

`examPoints` is not a list of inputs in the original code, but just one variable that gets overwritten with each iteration of the user-input loop:

```
for examPoints in range(1, 5):
    examPoints = input("Please enter students exam scores: ")
```

Instead, you want to keep each input separately. 
e.g. by appending it to a list:

```
examPoints = []
for _ in range(1,5):
    # add input to list after converting it to an integer
    examPoints.append(int(input("Please enter students exam scores: ")))
...
```

The input-text-to-integer conversion can be done either as you are appending (return error to user immediately upon input that can't be converted), or when you're performing the sum, by using a list comprehension or the map function:

```
# sum version
sum([int(v) for v in examPoints])
# map version
sum(map(int, examPoints))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but (In my opinion) your code is a bit messy. Instead, try:

```
def getExamPoints(examPoints):
    points = []
    for examPoints in range(1, 5):
        points = points + [int(input("Please enter students exam scores: "))]
    totalPoints = input("Please enter total possible points: ")
    print("The total exam points are: " + sum(examPoints))
    avg = float(int(str(examPoints))/int(totalPoints))
    print("the average is: ", avg)
```

what sum() looks for is an iterable object, like a list, and adds together everything in it. Since examPoints is defined as an integer, it is not iterable. Instead, make a separate list, and put the input inside there.